# Android google maps v2 navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using google map v2 for showing locations in my application. When I want to navigate to that particular location I use the following code which starts the default navigation application installed in my phone.

```
Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=aa,bb&daddr=xx,yy"));
startActivity(navigation);
```

So obviously we will leave our application and go to the default navigation application. Is there any chance that I can do the turn-by-turn navigation within the google map which is to be shown in my application itself?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to display a route between 2 points on the map in your application?

Comment: @liangricha Not just display the route, but also navigate just like default android map would navigate.

Comment: If you only want to display the route and have list of turn-by-turn directions, then it can be done.

Comment: Yup! In addition to that I want to do turn-by-turn navigation. Pavel's answer clarified my doubt. Thanks for the help!

Comment: for implementing navigation in custom way try this http://stackoverflow.com/q/25765972/3020568

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any chance that I can do this navigation within the google map which is shown in my application itself?

Unfortunately no. Google does not expose turn-by-turn navigation engine, so the maximum you can get with Google Map V2 is display route using route points returned from Route API. Actual turn-by-turn needs to be done via proprietary Google Navigation app

Comment: Google directions api provides turn by turn navigation.

Comment: Hi @Pavel Dudka can u plz describe how to display rout using Route points ?

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can display map in our application using MapFragment. Below is an example for such a activity inside which you can add the mapfragment.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

     <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/fragmap"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: for directions use this-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
                + destLat + ","
                + destLong + "&daddr="
                + srcLat + "," + strLong));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have google map already shown in my application. I want to navigate to a destination within my application itself without launching any other application.

Comment: Edited the answer, please check now. Also please explain the downvote.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer. And also i don't want to start an intent. I want to show navigation within my application itself.

Comment: Pavel Dudka got my question right! Thats what I was expecting. Thanks for the help though!